# Does move assign an std::fstream close the original stream

Tags: c++, filestream, move

Since c++11, we can move assign one `std::fstream` object to another, but I'm unable to find documentation that states, what happens if the `fstream` object is already associated with a file (`is_open()==true`).

So my question is whether in the following code, `File1.txt` will properly be closed or if I have to close it manually. And if I have to do it manually, what happens if I don't?

```
std::fstream file("File1.txt");   
file = std::fstream("File2.txt"); //will this implicitly call file.close()?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move-assignment of an `fstream` object will result in move-assignment of its associated `filebuf`.  The documentation for that makes it pretty clear that the old file is closed first (as-if `file.rdbuf()->close()` not `file.close()`):

> **`basic_filebuf& operator=(basic_filebuf&& rhs);`**
>
> 1. Effects: Calls `this->close()` then move assigns from `rhs`. After the move assignment `*this` has the observable state it would have had if it had been move constructed from `rhs`.
> 2. Returns: `*this`.
>
> **`basic_fstream& operator=(basic_fstream&& rhs);`**
>
> 1. Effects: Move assigns the base and members of `*this` from the base and corresponding members of `rhs`.
> 2. Returns: `*this`.

(This is the wording from draft n4527, unchanged since at least n3485)

Comment: Do you know, if this was already stated in older versions (in particular the c++11 version) of the standard?

Comment: @MikeMB: n3485 seems to have the same exact wording.

Comment: Damn, reading the standard really isn't my strong suit. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Since actual file-related machinery is 'hidden' inside corresponding buffers (streams really mostly provide formatting IO), you should be looking at `std::basic_filebuf` documentation:

> First calls close() to close the associated file, then moves the
>   contents of rhs into *this: the put and get buffers, the associated
>   file, the locale, the openmode, the is_open flag, and any other state.
>   After the move, rhs is not associated with a file and rhs.is_open() ==
>   false.

Copy from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/operator%3D

Comment: Yes, but this talks only about the rhs - it doesn't say, what exactly happens to the state of the lhs right?

Comment: @MikeMB, ' including the buffers, the associated file, the locale, the openmode, the is_open variable' is not good enough for you?

Comment: @SergeyA: Your answer completely avoids talking about what moving the buffer does to the buffer being replaced.

Comment: If I have a class with a raw pointer and I just copy everything from the rhs, that doesn't mean, I am deleting what that pointer points to.

Comment: @BenVoigt, my bad. I read the question as being about constructor, not assignment operator. Edited.